# get all the value from array while using filter method in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs, react-native

Lets say I have array:-

```
data = ['abc abc abc', 'def', 'ghi','abc','abc e']
```

and I want to filter all the value from array which have 'abc'.

my expected output is `newArray = ['abc abc abc','abc','abc e']`

So I tried:-

```
var newArray = data.map(item=>({ 
    item.split(" ").filter(function (getValue) {
  return getValue =='abc';
})
}
))
```

But its giving me error.

How can I do that?
Thanks!!!

Comment: `data.filter(elem => elem.includes('abc'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```js
let data = ['abc abc abc', 'def', 'ghi','abc','abc e']


let myArr = data.filter(element => element.match(/abc/g))

console.log(myArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#filter` with [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
const data = ['abc abc abc', 'def', 'ghi','abc','abc e'],
      result = data.filter(w => w.includes('abc'));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of .includes array method to achieve the same

```js
var data = ['abc abc abc', 'def', 'ghi','abc','abc e'];

var result = data.filter(obj => obj.includes('abc'));

console.log(result);
```